# how do i show popup/alert and then RedirectToAction()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I wish to display a Javascript type popup to alert the user that he has to fill in some additional data in a previous View before continue processing this View, and then actually redirect the user to that View.

At the moment my code is as follows :-

```
        if (viewModel.compData.GG != "")
            CalcGradingPoints();
        else
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('You have to Select a Grading before doing this calculation');</script>");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Grading");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
```

It is redirecting correctly, however I cannot see the error message, so for the user, it is like he is stuck on the first View and not moving.

How can I display an error message, allow the user to confirm that he saw the message by clicking the message, and then redirecting?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `confirm()` function : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm

usage :

```
if (confirm("Your question")) { 
 window.location = "http://www.google.com/" //redirect HERE
}
```

Comment: I did change to confirm :-                 Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>confirm('You have to Select a Global Grade from the Scope Matrix first before doing this calculation');</script>");
but still redirecting without a confirm button

Comment: you can add whatever code you want if you encapsulate the confirm in a IF statement. see my edit

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` is 302 HTTP redirect, you will never see anything with `Response.Write`. I also had same scenario and create for with logic separate view, where I show message and then redirect user. My model contain: title, message, controller, action and etc. Then you just fill view and create link with `@Url.Action`.

meta example:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.your-link.com">
```

The content="0; may be changed to the number of seconds you want the browser to wait before redirecting.

Comment: can you give me more details on your solution?

Comment: @Johann It depends on your logic, I am using automatic redirect with meta and/or javascript `document.location`, if user is faster, then he could navigate with clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the alert in ACTION method to inform the same

Answer (score 0):

Actually I thought there was an easy way to do it.  I have taken a different approach and set everything on the first View to a default value, so that the second View will never be blank.

Thanks for your help